# Does BitLocker encrypt everything?

Tags: encryption, bitlocker

just a quick question - does BitLocker encrypt everything including host protected area, device configuration overlay and bad sectors?

Comment: why would it need to?

Answer (score 1):

Bitlocker works at the volume level, replacing the file system metadata with its own and moving the FS metadata into the encrypted volume (for this reason, BitLocker needs to understand the file system format, so it knows where there is free space for the metadata, and how to mark that space as no longer free). It is Full **Volume** Encryption, not Full **Disk** Encryption, and doesn't touch anything outside of a logical volume (which might be a physical partition, or a RAID volume, or possibly something else).

I don't know if BitLocker has any special logic for dealing with bad sectors.

Comment: Wouldn't the firmware on the hard drive handle bad sectors transparently to the OS?

Comment: @johndoe  In an ideal world firmware would handle bad sectors.  However, in realty they don't.  Users still need chkdsk /R.